# Different ping and download speed between Windows and Linux machines

Tags: network, wifi

I'm seeing significant differences in download and ping speeds between my Linux and Windows machines.

```
Linux(galliumos)
Ping: 15
Dl:73.76Mbps
Up:12.23Mbps

Windows 10
Ping:31
Dl:19.79Mbps
Up:11.21Mbps
```

I'm connected through wifi.

I'm a networking noob so have no idea what causes/caused this discrepancy. Can a Windows machine show similar symptoms if it has been compromised, or is what I'm seeing normal?

edit: I've run speed tests a few more times and it seems the download/upload speed isn't consistent on the window machine. Sometimes I get 60Mbps down (rare), mostly around 18 - 20Mbps and sometimes as low as 4 - 8Mbps down. On the other hand, the the Linux machine stayed around 60 - 75Mbp constantly and occasionally dipped to 50Mbps.

Comment: There can be a several reasons for fluctuations in your network performance. It's very difficult to judge just based on your internet speed. You can use wireshark and inspect your packets to see if any malicious process is using your bandwith

Comment: Other than observed speed discrepancies,  do you have any other reason to believe your system has been compromised? Have you run malware / virus scans?

Comment: Are they different physical machines?

Comment: No, there isn't any reason reason beside the speed discrepancies.im just paranoid. I use avira and do regular scans and there hasn't been any red flags.

Comment: yup, they are different physical machines.

Comment: This is apparently not related to IT Security. I'm voting to move this question to SuperUser.

Comment: Not only are there tons of reasons why 2 OS's might have different speeds, but you aren't comparing the same hardware. Too many variables to account for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows systems, enabling power saving modes ("Power Plans") can reduce networking performance (especially with wireless connections). My laptop with CentOS 7 and Windows 7 experiences the same effect, until I set my Windows Power Plan to be "High Performance". After that, download speeds are identical, if not close enough.

Super User has a post about how to change power plans: https://superuser.com/questions/957500/easy-way-to-switch-power-plan-in-windows-10

Comment: The key part to note is the default power plan is "Balanced", as it was in Windows 7.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. If you could check my answer as correct, that would be great.